# Is there a method that is ALWAYS called in a webform?

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

I need to include a code like this:

```
IWebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(Proxy, ProxyPort);
NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential();

nc.UserName = ProxyLogin;
nc.Password = ProxyPassword;
proxy.Credentials = nc;
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = proxy;
```

in my WebForm application. But many parts of my projects start from different places: different masterpage, single page called with ajax, and so on!

Is there a common place where I can put it? So every time I call a page is guaranteed that my WebRequest use a proxy....

Comment: I would have a `base class` which inherits from `Page` and then all your pages inherit from the base class. within your base class on `Load` you could then add what you want and all pages that inherit from this class would execute the code.

Comment: @SecretSquirrel: can you give to me part of the code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can place it in an [application-level event handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwzzh56s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in Global.asax.cs, such as [BeginRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    // your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Or - if suitable - declare it once in ApplicationStart and reference it statically in any page

Comment: Is this valid also if I call a WebService inside this project?

Comment: And why `Global.asax.cs`? I cannot just use only `Global.asax`?

Comment: @markzzz: yes that method is also called for WebServices. You can also put it directly into Global.asax, but personally I prefer to have a "code-behind" file.

Comment: @markzzz: I don't understand. That's not mentioned in your original question. Please update/extend the question if you have more information.

Comment: Sorry, Wrong place ;)